# tensorflow AttentionCellWrapper implementation does not seem right

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, attention-model

I'm watching AttentionCellWrapper implementation in Tensorflow, but I'm confused. Attention decoder uses the source sequence's hidden states. But in Tensorflow's implementation below, because the attention values aka source sequence's hidden state slice and append cell output every time. I'm not sure if I'm right. Could anyone figure it out?

```
def call(self, inputs, state):
  """Long short-term memory cell with attention (LSTMA)."""
  if self._state_is_tuple:
    state, attns, attn_states = state
  else:
    states = state
    state = array_ops.slice(states, [0, 0], [-1, self._cell.state_size])
    attns = array_ops.slice(
      states, [0, self._cell.state_size], [-1, self._attn_size])
    attn_states = array_ops.slice(
      states, [0, self._cell.state_size + self._attn_size],
      [-1, self._attn_size * self._attn_length])
  attn_states = array_ops.reshape(attn_states,
                                [-1, self._attn_length, self._attn_size])
  input_size = self._input_size
  if input_size is None:
    input_size = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1]
  inputs = _linear([inputs, attns], input_size, True)
  lstm_output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state)
  if self._state_is_tuple:
    new_state_cat = array_ops.concat(nest.flatten(new_state), 1)
  else:
    new_state_cat = new_state
  new_attns, new_attn_states = self._attention(new_state_cat, attn_states)
  with vs.variable_scope("attn_output_projection"):
    output = _linear([lstm_output, new_attns], self._attn_size, True)
  new_attn_states = array_ops.concat(
    [new_attn_states, array_ops.expand_dims(output, 1)], 1)
  new_attn_states = array_ops.reshape(
    new_attn_states, [-1, self._attn_length * self._attn_size])
  new_state = (new_state, new_attns, new_attn_states)
  if not self._state_is_tuple:
    new_state = array_ops.concat(list(new_state), 1)
  return output, new_state

def _attention(self, query, attn_states):
  conv2d = nn_ops.conv2d
  reduce_sum = math_ops.reduce_sum
  softmax = nn_ops.softmax
  tanh = math_ops.tanh

  with vs.variable_scope("attention"):
    k = vs.get_variable(
      "attn_w", [1, 1, self._attn_size, self._attn_vec_size])
    v = vs.get_variable("attn_v", [self._attn_vec_size])
    hidden = array_ops.reshape(attn_states,
                             [-1, self._attn_length, 1, self._attn_size])
    hidden_features = conv2d(hidden, k, [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME")
    y = _linear(query, self._attn_vec_size, True)
    y = array_ops.reshape(y, [-1, 1, 1, self._attn_vec_size])
    s = reduce_sum(v * tanh(hidden_features + y), [2, 3])
    a = softmax(s)
    d = reduce_sum(
      array_ops.reshape(a, [-1, self._attn_length, 1, 1]) * hidden, [1, 2])
    new_attns = array_ops.reshape(d, [-1, self._attn_size])
    new_attn_states = array_ops.slice(attn_states, [0, 1, 0], [-1, -1, -1])
    return new_attns, new_attn_states
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: simple architecture of the cell with AttentionCellWrapper]

I am pretty sure that tf.contrib.rnn.AttentionCellWrapper work as Fig 1 and you're correct.

Before start sequence's hidden states(as M in fig.1) is initialized to 0. 
Each timestep, hidden states slice its first column and append the output so that hidden states can save 1 to t-1 timestep's output.